# CodeIngiter "WHERE AND OR" to Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to make CodeIgniter Active Records query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = 'email' 
AND (user_password='123' OR second_password = '456')
```

I already tried some code, but not working. I am using CI 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with CI documentation you can write custom strings for where clause https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

```
$this->db->from('user');
$where = "user_name='email' AND (user_password='123' OR second_password = '456')";
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand version :

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

$this->db->where('username', $name)->where($where)->get('myTableName');
```

`$this->db->where()` already acting as `SELECT FROM *` Except you want to select some column only.

> **$this->db->select();** Note: If you are selecting all (*) from a table
>   you do not need to use this function

Answer (score 0):

I got a easy solution, Thanks all.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where('user_name', 'email');
$this->db->where('user_password', '123');
$this->db->or_where('user_name', 'email');
$this->db->where('second_password', '456');
$query = $this->db->get();
```